# HttpURLConnection setConnectTimeout not working

Tags: android, httpurlconnection

I am using HttpURLConnection to communicate with my server in my app. But I find out that if there is a bad connection of my android device, my app will be hanging for a long time and this is a bad User Experience. I use both setConnectTimeout() and setReadTimeout() but it seems not working. Here is my code below:

```
        URL url = null;
        HttpURLConnection connection = null;
        InputStreamReader ins = null;   
        try {
            url = new URL("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX");
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setConnectTimeout(10000);
            connection.setReadTimeout(10000);
            ins = new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream());  
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(ins);
            StringBuffer strBuffer = new StringBuffer();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                strBuffer.append(line);
            }       
            result = strBuffer.toString();       
            line = null;
            strBuffer = null;
            bufferedReader = null;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (connection != null) {
                connection.disconnect();
                connection = null;
            }
            if (ins != null) {
                try {
                    ins.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                ins = null;
            }
            url = null;
        }
```

From my code we can see that I use both setConnectTimeout() and setReadTimeout() when i have a poor internet connect. However, it still hang out for a very long time(more than 30 seconds or even more) and it will show such logs in the end:

```
    07-17 13:27:47.200: W/System.err(18005): java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "server.ibaobeimao.com": No address associated with hostname
    07-17 13:27:47.200: W/System.err(18005):    at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:424)
    07-17 13:27:47.200: W/System.err(18005):    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:236)
    07-17 13:27:47.200: W/System.err(18005):    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:214)
    07-17 13:27:47.200: W/System.err(18005):    at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:70)
    07-17 13:27:47.203: W/System.err(18005):    at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:50)
    07-17 13:27:47.207: W/System.err(18005):    at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection$Address.connect(HttpConnection.java:340)
    07-17 13:27:47.207: W/System.err(18005):    at libcore.net.http.HttpConnectionPool.get(HttpConnectionPool.java:87)
    07-17 13:27:47.207: W/System.err(18005):    at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.connect(HttpConnection.java:128)
    07-17 13:27:47.207: W/System.err(18005):    at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.openSocketConnection(HttpEngine.java:316)
    07-17 13:27:47.207: W/System.err(18005):    at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:311)
    07-17 13:27:47.210: W/System.err(18005):    at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:290)
    07-17 13:27:47.210: W/System.err(18005):    at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:240)
    07-17 13:27:47.210: W/System.err(18005):    at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:282)
    07-17 13:27:47.213: W/System.err(18005):    at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:177)
    07-17 13:27:47.213: W/System.err(18005):    at utils.Rpc.httpRequest(Rpc.java:49)
    07-17 13:27:47.213: W/System.err(18005):    at utils.Utils$11.run(Utils.java:1154)
    07-17 13:27:47.213: W/System.err(18005):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
    07-17 13:27:47.213: W/System.err(18005): Caused by: libcore.io.GaiException: getaddrinfo failed: EAI_NODATA (No address associated with hostname)
    07-17 13:27:47.217: W/System.err(18005):    at libcore.io.Posix.getaddrinfo(Native Method)
    07-17 13:27:47.217: W/System.err(18005):    at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.getaddrinfo(ForwardingOs.java:60)
    07-17 13:27:47.217: W/System.err(18005):    at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:405)
    07-17 13:27:47.217: W/System.err(18005):    ... 16 more
    07-17 13:27:47.217: W/System.err(18005): Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: getaddrinfo failed: ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)
    07-17 13:27:47.220: W/System.err(18005):    ... 19 more
```

So, what can i do to set a length of time for my HttpURLConnection timeout ? why is setConnectTimeout() and setReadTimeout() not working?

Here is my try that uses ping in android, but for some unkonwn reason, it still does't work, but i will lay out the method i used:

```
public static final boolean ping() {

    String result = null;
    try {
        String ip = "202.108.22.5"; // ping address
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/system/bin/ping -c 1 -w 10 " + ip); // ping 3 times

        InputStream input = p.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input));
        StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
        String content = "";
        while ((content = in.readLine()) != null) {
            stringBuffer.append(content);
        }

        // ping's situation
        int status = p.waitFor();
        if (status == 0) {
            result = "success";
            return true;
        } else {
            result = "failed";
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        result = "IOException";
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        result = "InterruptedException";
    } finally {
        Log.d("----result---", "result = " + result);
    }
    return false;
}
```

but my result is false all the time whenever i am really in connection with the internet or not. Could anybody give me some more advice?

Comment: Did you try to make this async? http://mobiledevtuts.com/android/android-http-with-asynctask-example/

Comment: thank you for your comment.  I will try the way from the website you give it to me as soon as possible.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is at lower networking layer unfortunately. Your parameters only come into play when it is requesting HTTP. You are stuck at resolving DNS. 
Sequence of event:

- Resolve dns
- Establish TCP connection
- Send HTTP request
- Receive HTTP response

The only thing I can think of to deal with this is to do a connection check like opening connection to google gen_204.

Comment: Thank you for your answer~  i have read it and is it the meaning that i need to ping a website such as google.com to check whether i could connect to the internet in deed ?

Comment: Yep. Otherwise system will try to resolve dns for a while before giving up.